# The script was unable to add a record to the database

Tags: python, mysql

this is my first MySQL Python program. I don't know why the script crashes, but I know it crashes when it is added to the database. The script function is designed to retrieve information from websites and add this information to the database. This feature will be used over and over again. Could someone help me? Sorry for linguistic errors "Google translate"

My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import mysql.connector

class bot():

    def __init__(self):
        self.mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
            host="localhost",
            user="root",
            password="",
            database="python"
        )
        self.mycursor = self.mydb.cursor()

    def __del__(self):
        self.mydb.commit()

    def add(self, url):
        self.odpowiedz = requests.get(url)
        if self.odpowiedz.status_code == 200:
            self.html = self.odpowiedz.text
            self.html2 = BeautifulSoup(self.html, 'html.parser')
            self.title = self.html2.title

            print("---")
            print(f"Tytuł: {self.title.string}")
            print(f"Adres: {url}")
            print("---")

            self.sql = "INSERT INTO adresy (title, url) VALUES (%s, %s)"
            self.val = (self.title, url)
            self.mycursor.execute(self.sql, self.val)



bot = bot()
bot.add("https://facebook.com")
```

Errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Tomek\PycharmProjects\scrapping\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\conversion.py", line 179, in to_mysql
return getattr(self, "_{0}_to_mysql".format(type_name))(value)
AttributeError: 'MySQLConverter' object has no attribute '_tag_to_mysql'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tomek\PycharmProjects\scrapping\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 417, in _process_params
    res = [to_mysql(i) for i in res]
  File "C:\Users\Tomek\PycharmProjects\scrapping\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 417, in <listcomp>
    res = [to_mysql(i) for i in res]
  File "C:\Users\Tomek\PycharmProjects\scrapping\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\conversion.py", line 181, in to_mysql
    raise TypeError("Python '{0}' cannot be converted to a "
TypeError: Python 'tag' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tomek\PycharmProjects\scrapping\main.py", line 38, in <module>
    bot.add("https://facebook.com")
  File "C:\Users\Tomek\PycharmProjects\scrapping\main.py", line 33, in add
    self.mycursor.execute(self.sql, self.val)
  File "C:\Users\Tomek\PycharmProjects\scrapping\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 539, in execute
    psub = _ParamSubstitutor(self._process_params(params))
  File "C:\Users\Tomek\PycharmProjects\scrapping\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 421, in _process_params
    raise errors.ProgrammingError(
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'tag' cannot be converted to a MySQL type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add to MySQL the `bs4` tag:

```py
print(type(self.title))

>>> <class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
```

instead of the corresponding string:

```py
print(type(self.title.string))

>>> <class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>
```

Try to add to mysql exactly the same what you are printing:

```py
self.val = (self.title.string, url)
```

instead of

```py
self.val = (self.title, url)
```

or cast it to string:

```py
self.val = (str(self.title.string), url)
```